# C++: bizarre occurrence of "Request for member X of Y which is of non-class type Z"

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

The following program, compiled with g++ 4.6, yields the error

```
request for member ‘y’ in ‘a2’, which is of non-class type ‘A<B>(B)’
```

at its last line:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> class A
{
public:
  T y;
  A(T x):y(x){}
};

class B
{
public:
  int u;
  B(int v):u(v){}
};

int main()
{
  int v = 10;
  B b1(v);

  //works
  A<B> a1(b1);

  //does not work (the error is when a2 is used)
  A<B> a2(B(v));

  //works
  //A<B> a2((B(v)));

  std::cout << a1.y.u << " " << a2.y.u << std::endl;    
}
```

As can be seen from the working variant included in the code, adding parentheses around the arguments of the constructor of A solves the problem.

I have seen some related errors caused by a the interpretation of a constructor invocation as a function declaration, like when creating an object with no argument to its constructor, but with braces:

```
myclass myobj();
```

but it seems to me that

```
A<B> a2(B(v));
```

cannot be interpreted as a function declaration.

Someone can explain to me what is happening?

Comment: It seems to me as a case of [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a case of **most vexing parse** where the compiler interprets `A<B> a2(B(v))` as the declaration of a function. Such that:

`A<B>` is the return type
`a2` is the function name
`B` is the type of the argument
`v` is the argument name

So, when you are doing

```
std::cout << a1.y.u << " " << a2.y.u << std::endl;
```

The compiler does not think of `a2.y.u` as a class, that's why you are getting the `non-class type` error.

Also, since **double parenthesis aren't allowed in a function declaration**, the version `A<B> a2((B(v)));` works because the compiler doesn't interprets it as a function declaration anymore, but as a variable declaration.

Comment: A more interesting question is how come that `v` being an integer variable, the expression `A<B> a2(B(v));` can be parsed as a function declaration... (which is actually the question asked) --It seems clear from the comments at the end that the user already knew this was a case of the most-vexing-parse but wanted to know *how* the compiler got there.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You are right, I added how the compiler interpreted the line itself.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realized the most vexing parse could get this bad. `int foo(int (bar)) { return 0; }` Why are parentheses allowed around the argument name? I had thought the most vexing parse only happened when the initializer could be parsed as a function type. Now I see that because parameter declarations can have parenthesis around the parameter name it's worse than that. I guess I'm surprised that they didn't go ahead and make 'disambiguating' parentheses legal for function declarations as well so we couldn't disambiguate: `int foo((int (bar))) { return 0; }`

Comment: Apparently the parens are allowed because they're allowed in normal variable declarations: `int main() { int (bar) = 0; }` Why?

Comment: @bames53 The same way they are needed in int (*f)() to declare a function pointer, I think they need to be uniformelly allowed in other situations.

Comment: I think it's worth to mention the golden rule here: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations

Comment: One more thing to note: you can use C++11's uniform initialization syntax to get around this vexing parse: A<B> a2{B(v)};

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that it was allowed to put parentheses around function argument names. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting bit by the "most vexing parse", meaning that `A<B> a2(B(v));` is getting parsed as function declaration instead of a variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the following code sample:

```
int a (int(v)) {
    return v;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << a(5); //prints 5
}
```

That line is indeed a declaration. In this example, the parameter is of type `int` and named `v`. Relating that to your code, the parameter is of type `B` and is named `v`. That's why you get the similar behaviour when you use double parentheses: because it's the same thing!

Comment: +1 At last, one answer that explains **why** that can be parsed as a function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

It is a function declaration:

```
A<B> a2(B(v));
//is same as:
A<B> a2(B v);

//consider:
int foo(int v);
int foo(int (v));
```