# c++11 std::thread compiles with function, but not class

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am using g++ 4.7 with the c++11 flag. In this demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class do_work
{
public:
   void operator()()
   {
     std::cout << "Doing work..." << std::endl;
   }
};

void foo()
{

}

int main()
{
  // Does not work
  std::thread t(do_work);
  t.join(); // error: request for member ‘join’ in ‘t’, which is of non-class type ‘std::thread(do_work)’

  // Works
  std::thread t2(foo);
  t2.join();

  return 0;
}
```

I can successfully call join() on a thread that was created with a function as its constructor argument, but I cannot call join() (see the error inline) on a thread that was created with a functor as its constructor argument. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: bizarre occurrence of "Request for member X of Y which is of non-class type Z"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138543/c-bizarre-occurrence-of-request-for-member-x-of-y-which-is-of-non-class-type)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've declared `t` as a function taking `do_work` and returning `std::thread`.

You probably want to write

```
do_work worker;
std::thread t{worker};
```

or

```
std::thread t{do_work{}};
```

or

```
std::thread t((do_work()));
```

Note that

```
std::thread t(do_work());
```

won't work; it's [vexingly parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec) as declaring a function `t` taking a function that takes no arguments and returns `do_work`, and returning `std::thread`.  Wrapping the `do_work` temporary with parentheses or using uniform initializer syntax (at any point) will fix it.

This is a good reason to get into the habit of using uniform initializer syntax wherever possible; if you'd written

```
std::thread t{do_work};  // incorrect
```

then compilation would have failed on that line instead of the `join`.

Comment: Ah, excellent. I'm glad my silly mistake led me to learn a real thing instead of just being a "doh!" moment :)